# How to get domain name with port no in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I know that by following lines of code we can get domain name but not sure about how to get port no. Can somebody help me on this

```
//importing
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//Injection
export class domainUtil {
    domain:string;
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }

    returnHostname(){
        this.domain = this.document.location.hostname;
        console.log("*****Domain Name*******"+this.domain);//Returning domain name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.location.port`

in angular, it would be

```
this.port = this.document.location.port;
```